# How to toggle Org-mode source code block ":eval no" status

Tags: org-mode, elisp

I often limit or unlimit the evaluation of specific code blocks in org-mode babel using [`:eval`](http://orgmode.org/manual/eval.html#eval) header argument.

Here's an example:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value scalar :eval no
(+ 1 1)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 2
```

I toggle the code blocks between `:eval no` and `:eval n` (or delete `:eval no` completely) by hand.

`#+PROPERTY: eval no` is convenient, but is not suited for each code block.

Are there any better ways to toggle the `:eval` status handy, like below?

```
C-c C-t     (org-todo)
Rotate the TODO state of the current item among
(unmarked) -> TODO -> DONE
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've come up with a relatively nice solution, which relies on the `org-in-block-p` function, which I'd recommend taking a look. Add the following code to you `init.el` file:

```lisp
    (defun org-toggle-src-eval-no ()
      "Will toggle ':eval no' on the src block begin line"

      (defun in-src-block-p ()
        "Returns t when the point is inside a source code block"
        (string= "src" (org-in-block-p '("src"))))
    
      (defun beginning-src ()
        "Find the beginning of the src block"
        (let ((case-fold-search t)) (search-backward "#+BEGIN_SRC")))
    
      (defun toggle-eval-no ()
        "Handles the toggling of ' :eval no'"
         (save-excursion
          (end-of-line)
          (let ((case-fold-search t)) (search-backward "#+BEGIN_SRC")
           (if (search-forward " :eval no" (line-end-position) "f")
               (replace-match "")
             (insert " :eval no")
             ))))
    
      (if (in-src-block-p) (toggle-eval-no)))

    (defun add-org-toggle-src-key ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "C-c t") (lambda () (interactive) (org-toggle-src-eval-no))))

    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'add-org-toggle-src-key)
```

This defines the function `org-toggle-src-eval-no` and it should do exactly what you want; anytime you're inside a code block, it will toggle the presence of `:eval no`. I have bound it to `C-c t`, but feel free to map it to whatever you'd like. Happy org-ing.

Comment: Amazing! It's really great! This is exactly what i wanted! I did not expect to get the solution so quickly. Meanwhile I noticed just one trivial thing. When I have 2 code blocks, if I C-c t at the beginning of a line of second #+BEGIN_SRC block, the first code block get toggled. Perhaps I should add (move-end-of-line nil) before both of (search-backward "#+BEGIN_SRC") ?

Comment: Excellent point. I've updated my answer to include `(end-of-line)` before the search, which moves the point to the end of the `#+BEGIN_SRC` if you're before it (without limiting any other functionality). Let me know if you're still having problems.

Comment: I thank you for your code! It's really great!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was looking for such a functionality for a long time :)